# image hash of file is not valid

Tags: windows-7, event-log, data-loss-prevention

I'm receiving the following errors in the security event log on a windows 7 x32 machine.

There are a couple of them and I'm worried that it might indicate a coming drive failure.

Am I right to worry?  Event below:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          12/16/2010 9:12:33 AM
Event ID:      5038
Task Category: System Integrity
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Failure
User:          N/A
Computer:      ThisMachineName
Description:
Code integrity determined that the image hash of a file is not valid.  The file could be corrupt due to unauthorized modification or the invalid hash could indicate a potential disk device error.

File Name:  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\drivers\DGIVECP.SYS    
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>5038</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12290</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8010000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-12-16T15:12:33.026367100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>32974</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="44" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>ThisMachineName</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\drivers\DGIVECP.SYS</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

**EDIT**

There were a couple of different ones with the same issue:
File Name:  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\drivers\SSPORT.SYS
File Name:  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\drivers\CVPNDRVA.sys

The CVPNDRVA relates to Cisco VPN software, I believe both DGIVECP and SSPORT are related to a samsung printer.

I took a longer look and it appears that only these three drivers are referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it's a dell printer driver component.  Is it unsigned or something?  I would just find the driver installer, extract, and compare to see if it's a patched library(bad) or a signing issue(not so bad).

reference on what owns this file: http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1298284

Comment: I think you're right.  It looks like it's limited to just a samsung printer driver and a cisco vpn client.  No other files are mentioned.

Comment: another approach is to run sfc /scannow to check MS owned libraries and fix